# Dirac distribution δ(x-x)

Tags: mathematical-physics, distribution-theory

When canonically quantising a scalar field without normal ordering, one comes across the following expression:

$$\int_\mathbb{R}E(x)\delta(x-x)dx.$$
Here, $E(x)$ is a smooth unbound function.

I have read that this is infinity because, 'the value of the Dirac function at zero is infinity.'

For obvious reasons, this explanation is very unsatisfying - $\delta$ is not a function but a distribution. And the first question therefore is: How does the expression

$$\int\varphi(x)\delta(x-x)dx$$

mathematically make sense? And for this, let's first assume that $\varphi$ is a Schwartz-function, unlike $E(x)$. I know that $\int\varphi(x)\delta(x-a)dx=\varphi(a)$. But here $a$ is a constant!

The second question is then how does the above equation make sense, if you swap $\varphi$ for $E$.

Comment: The expression $\delta(x-x)=\delta(0)$ doesn't make sense. I suspect the QFT argument which led to the first integral above is faulty. Note that $\delta(0)$ typically is the volume of spacetime. So there must have been a careless infinite volume limit taken.

Comment: Aha! So it is indeed undefined

Comment: I remember there was a good treatment of this kind of issues in the old book by T.D. Lee https://www.amazon.com/Particle-Physics-Introduction-Contemporary-Concepts/dp/3718600331 He introduced canonical quantization  by working on a lattice and in a box $\Omega$. In the course of the explanation you see how $vol(\Omega)$ becomes $\delta(0)$. This gets even worse when you consider scattering cross sections.

Comment: I have read one can get rid off this problem by normalising your Hamiltonian by the Volume, i.e. considering an energy density?